# Lines not overlapping as expected

Tags: html, css

In the below code, I have 2 sections with a common border initially and while hovering each section, I want each section to be highlighted with a border. I want the lines to overlap. Please help.

```css
.slides li {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 48%;
  float: left;
  padding: 1%;
}

.slides li:hover {
  border-top: solid 4px red;
}

.slides {
  border-top: solid 3px #979797;
}
```

```html
<ul class="slides">
  <li>
    <div class="slider-caption">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.ut sapien cursus, non posuere sapien sagit.</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="slider-caption">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elitm vehicula commodo. Nam consectetur augue ut sapien cursus, non posuere sapien sagit.</p>
    </div>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the same pixel border for hover and add negative margin top when the hover happened like `margin-top:-3px:`. So this will fix the overlay.

```css
.slides li {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 48%;
  float: left;
  padding: 1%;
}

.slides li:hover {
  border-top: solid 3px red;
  margin-top:-3px;
}

.slides {
  border-top: solid 3px #979797;
}
```

```html
<ul class="slides">
  <li>
    <div class="slider-caption">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.ut sapien cursus, non posuere sapien sagit.</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="slider-caption">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elitm vehicula commodo. Nam consectetur augue ut sapien cursus, non posuere sapien sagit.</p>
    </div>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Apply the gery border on li itself.

```css
.slides li {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 48%;
  float: left;
  padding: 1%;
  border-top: solid 3px #979797; 
}

.slides li:hover {
  border-top: solid 4px red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="slides">
  <li>
    <div class="slider-caption">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.ut sapien cursus, non posuere sapien sagit.</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="slider-caption">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elitm vehicula commodo. Nam consectetur augue ut sapien cursus, non posuere sapien sagit.</p>
    </div>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep negative `margin` along with a transparent `border-top` on each `li` element.

There is a transition effect also applied in solution.

```css
.slides li {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 48%;
  float: left;
  padding: 1%;
  transition: .7s all;
  border-top: solid 3px transparent;
  margin-top: -3px;
}

.slides li:hover {
  border-top: solid 3px red;
}

.slides {
  border-top: solid 3px #979797;
}
```

```html
<ul class="slides">
  <li>
    <div class="slider-caption">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.ut sapien cursus, non posuere sapien sagit.</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="slider-caption">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elitm vehicula commodo. Nam consectetur augue ut sapien cursus, non posuere sapien sagit.</p>
    </div>
  </li>

</ul>
```